# How do I skip items in array if value is 0

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, frontend

Let's say I have an array of scores:

```js
const scores = [20, 0, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120];
```

By default, I'm displaying current month's score (`scores[0]`) and previous month's score (`scores[1]`).

If previous month is `0`, I want to display the last index with a value that isn't zero. (`scores[2]` in this instance). Meaning is we have `0` values from index `1` to `8`, I want to display index `9` as previous month's score

```js
for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  if (scores[i] === 0) {
    // At this point I want to skip to the next index.
    // If the next index is also zero, I skip till I get an index with a value
  }
}
```

Comment: `while ( scores[i] === 0 ) i++;`

Comment: What is the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to use the [`continue`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/continue) statement, just like this:

```js
const scores = [20, 0, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120]; 
for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
    if (scores[i] === 0) {
        continue;
    }
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Array#find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to get the first non-zero element.

```js
let res = scores.find((x, i) => i && x !== 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use `continue` which basically skips to the next iteration so your code will look something like this:

```
for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
  if (scores[i] === 0) {
    continue;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to the the first non-zero value, just locate the first index starting at 0. After you find that value, search for the next value that follows that index.

```js
const fromIndex = (callbackFn, fromIndex) =>
  (element, index, array) =>
    index >= fromIndex && callbackFn(element, index, array);

const getBreakdown = (scores, criteria) => {
  const currentIndex = scores.findIndex(criteria);
  const previousIndex = scores.findIndex(fromIndex(criteria, currentIndex + 1));
  return {
    current: scores[currentIndex],
    previous: scores[previousIndex],
  };
};

const
  scores = [20, 0, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120],
  breakdown = getBreakdown(scores, (score) => score > 0);

console.log(breakdown);
```

Alternatively, you could always filter non-zero values:

```js
const getBreakdown = (scores, criteria) => {
  const [current, previous] = scores.filter(criteria);
  return { current, previous };
};

const
  scores = [20, 0, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 110, 120],
  breakdown = getBreakdown(scores, (score) => score > 0);

console.log(breakdown);
```